# storing database information using python/django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a table that I am filtering to return data with a specific session_id. using django/python I want to store all this information into and array and send it back using the response. here is the view I have written so far.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def sessiondetail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sessid = request.body
        sessionid = json.loads(sessid)
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM meter_meterdata WHERE session_id = %s ORDER BY meter_meterdata.time_elapsed", [sessionid])
        result_list = []
        for row in c.fetchall():
            d = meterdata.objects.get(time_elapsed=row[1], volts=row[2], amps=row[3], kW=row[4], kWh=row[5])
            result_list.append(d)
    return HttpResponse(result_list)
```

using the sqlite shell in linux I know the select statement gets exaclty what I want, but the result_list returned is just the session_id over and over. If there are 9 reading with session_id = 1 result list will return [111111111] how do I put all the data into an array I can use on the client side?

Comment: Have you checked out the Django provided libraries for managing sessions? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Have you checked out the Django provided libraries for requesting database? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/db/queries/ And to generate models from existing db: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb